# Vertex Labeling Problem in a Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I am using following codes to create a graph.

```
 cities = CityData[{All, #}] & /@ {"Germany"}; bigcities = 
 Select[Select[Join @@ cities, FreeQ[#, ""] &], 
 CityData[#, "Population"] > 100000 &];
 cityCoords = 
 Select[CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ bigcities, FreeQ[#, ""] &];
 Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
 pts = Reverse[cityCoords, 2];
 dt = DelaunayTriangulation[pts];
 toPairs[{m_, ns_List}] := Map[{m, #} &, ns];
 edges = Union[Sort /@ Flatten[toPairs /@ dt, 1]];
 Graph[edges, ImagePadding -> 20, GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding", 
 VertexCoordinates -> pts, VertexStyle -> LightBlue, 
 VertexLabels -> bigcities[[All, 1]], 
 Prolog -> {LightBrown, EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
 CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"]}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

But the problem is it doesn't change the labeling of vertexes into the name of cities.How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this inside your `Graph` for a quick fix:

```
VertexLabels -> Table[i -> First@bigcities[[i]], {i, 1, Length[bigcities]}]
```

[image: germany]

`VertexLabels` doesn't appear to like a simple list, judging from the documentation:

[image: documentation for VertexLabels]

Following halmir's excellent solution in the comments, you can do this:

```
rules = Table[i -> First@bigcities[[i]], {i, 1, Length[bigcities]}]

    {1 -> "Berlin", 2 -> "Hamburg", 3 -> "Munich", 4 -> "Cologne", 
     5 -> "Frankfurt", 6 -> "Stuttgart", 7 -> "Dortmund", 8 -> "Essen", 
     9 -> "Dusseldorf", 10 -> "Bremen", 11 -> "Hanover", 12 -> "Leipzig", 
     13 -> "Dresden", 14 -> "Nuremberg", 15 -> "Duisburg", 16 -> "Bochum",
     17 -> "Wuppertal", ...
```

> ```
> Graph[
>  rules[[All, 2]], (UndirectedEdge @@@ edges) /. rules,
>  VertexLabels -> "Name",
>  VertexCoordinates -> pts,
>  VertexStyle -> LightBlue,
>  Prolog -> {LightBrown, EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
>    CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"]},
>  ImageSize -> 800]
> ```

using the second syntax of `Graph`:

[image: graph second syntax]

Comment: many thanks this is my answer.Could you please tell me if there is anyway to change the `VertexList` of the current `Graph` to related city name here that you labeled?You know the `VertexList` is still that numbers.I know this is different question

Comment: @alex - I don't know how to do that... :(

Comment: *alex - you can just use city names as vertices. For example: rules = Table[i -> First@bigcities[[i]], {i, 1, Length[bigcities]}]; Graph[rules[[All, 2]], (UndirectedEdge @@@ edges) /. rules, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]

Comment: @halmir That's the way - thanks! I'll update my answer with your solution.

Comment: @halmir thanks for the answer